# Should a pod in a MicroK8s cluster be able to reach a pod on a different node via a ClusterIP?

Tags: kubernetes, raspberry-pi4, microk8s

I have set up a MicroK8s two node cluster running on two Raspberry Pi 4s.
To set up the cluster I followed these instructions: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-kubernetes-cluster-on-raspberry-pi#1-overview

When choosing a channel I ran: `sudo snap install microk8s --classic --channel=latest/stable`

Running `microk8s version` gives: MicroK8s v1.26.1 revision 4567.

Both Pis are running Ubuntu 22.10 (GNU/Linux 5.19.0-1014-raspi aarch64).
If I SSH to both nodes, they can both ping each other via their host names and they both have static IP addresses.

I've also enabled rback, dns and metallb addons.

I then created the following deployment:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-one
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-one
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-one
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-one
        image: nginx:latest
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/hostname: k8s-master
```

And the following service:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-one-cluster-ip-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx-one
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 80
```

I then added a second deployment:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-two
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-two
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-two
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-two
        image: nginx:latest
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/hostname: k8s-master
```

With the above applied, both pods run on the same node.

If I exec into the "nginx-two" pod, I can run...

```
curl http://nginx-one-cluster-ip-svc:8080
```

...and I'll get the expected HTML back. All great.

But, if I move the "nginx-two" pod to the other node (by changing the nodeSelector) and exec into the pod, the same curl command fails:

```
root@nginx-two-d6d8996c8-25nbr:/# curl -v http://nginx-one-cluster-ip-svc:8080
* Could not resolve host: nginx-one-cluster-ip-svc
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: nginx-one-cluster-ip-svc
```

Using the IP of the service doesn't work either:

```
curl -v http://10.152.183.124:8080
*   Trying 10.152.183.124:8080...
* connect to 10.152.183.124 port 8080 failed: Connection timed out
* Failed to connect to 10.152.183.124 port 8080: Connection timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 10.152.183.124 port 8080: Connection timed out
```

Should this work? Should the ClusterIP be reachable from the other node? And if so, does anybody have any troubleshooting ideas for why it's not working here?

Comment: Make sure `kube-proxy` is running on both nodes in the cluster (runs as daemonset). Also verify `CoreDNS` is running and verify the logs to see if there is any error.

Comment: Doesn't look like `kube-proxy` is running.
`kubectl get daemonsets --all-namespaces` only shows `metallb-system` and `kube-system`.
`sudo microk8s inspect` on the master node doesn't list it either.
How would I install/start it though? I've done a quick google but I can't see how?

Comment: The `CoreDNS` addon is enabled, but how would I confirm if it is running?

Comment: Which logs should I be looking at? The logs for the "nginx-two" pod?

Comment: I am not sure how the control plane components run as in `microk8s`. If they are running as pods, `kubectl get pods -n kube-system` should show you both `kube-proxy` & 'coredns' pods in case they are already there.

Comment: No, there's no pods for kube-proxy running.
I've noticed [in the Microk8s docs](https://microk8s.io/docs/configuring-services#snapmicrok8sdaemon-proxy-3) that "Starting with release 1.21, daemon-proxy was consolidated into daemon-kubelite". 
I'm not sure if that makes a difference here though.

Comment: @DanMcCoy Seems like I am stuck in the same problem. Were you able to figure out this problem